# Keras custom metric doesn't work as loss function

Tags: keras, tensorflow, regression, loss-function

Referencing my previous question [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/88187/how-to-create-custom-keras-metric-using-multiple-functions-with-numpy-arrays-and).
I've managed to get my angular error metric working with tf.py_function;

```
ang_error = tf.py_function(angular_error, [data_true, data_pred], tf.float32)
```

but when I use it for a loss function, I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  shape of dy was [] instead of [3]
 [[node gradient_tape/angular_error/strided_slice_1/StridedSliceGrad 
 (defined at <ipython-input-15-3ce535aaa0f9>:23) ]] 
 [Op:__inference_train_function_1113]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

The last layer where I want to use this metric as a loss function if defined as:

```
orientation = Dense(3, activation="linear", name='orientation')(base_output)
```